# Visual Studio Code taking much longer to open + stalls

Tags: visual-studio-code

Originally, VSCode used to open in under 5 seconds.
Now it takes about 60 seconds + there's a popup.
See attached image for popup.

[image: Problem popup]

I removed all extensions - same result still.
I uninstalled and reinstalled.
Still the same.
What's happening?
How can I fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe VSCode isn't causing it, like maybe your system is under load. Have you checked Task Manager? What are your system specs? It could even be an antivirus interfering with it. Here's an MS page that might help: [Tips to improve PC performance in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/tips-to-improve-pc-performance-in-windows-b3b3ef5b-5953-fb6a-2528-4bbed82fba96)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.